# How to filter [urls ]using package and not folder with Apache Shiro

Tags: security, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, shiro

Is it possible to use servlets's package name instead of JSP's folder to filter specific page?

Actually, i can filter the access to all JSP pages inside a given folder but what I want is to filter some servlets's urlPatterns.

example: let's suppose I have *`Servlet1`* and *`Servlet2`* inside the package *`com.myProject.controller`*:
can I use something like this to filter the urlPatterns of these Servlet:

```
[urls]  
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout 
/com.myProject.controller/** = user, roles[admin]
```

Comment: This would have been done in a Filter. But because the filter doesn't know which servlet will be chosen to process your request, it can't perform the package check. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Thank you, It's because all my JSP pages are accessed through a servlet, so I can protect them only by protecting their urlPatterns (as fa as I know). You see?

Comment: A JSP is just dynamic html that your application renders and then writes as bytes to the response. The logic for which jsp to dispatch to comes from your servlet. The logic itself probably looks at url path params, headers, or even the session. That's where your shiro filter should be operating, not on the package name.

Comment: ha ok, I see.  So their is no way to filter Servlet's urlPatterns  within the same package?

Comment: That question doesn't make any sense. The Servlet Container will get the url from the request and match it (using each declared servlet's urlpattern) to a single servlet. Then call the `service()` method on that servlet. What do you mean with the _within the same package_?